# PDF not displayed properly using Shinydashboard

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, shinydashboard

I wanted to embed a pdf file to Shinydashboard and it displays as expected when there is only one tab or I just use shiny without using dashboard. When I have two tabs, the PDF will display as a skinny bar ([see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcPdI.png)) under the second tab though I could click the button on the screen to adjust its size. Can someone help figure out what goes wrong? This only happens in Chrome but works fine in Edge or IE. Thanks in advance!

Sample code:

```
dashboardPage(      
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),

  ui<-dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Model", tabName = "model"),
      menuItem("Instruction", tabName = "inst"),
      id = "tabm"
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "model",
              h2("first tab content"),
              tags$iframe(style="height:650px; width:100%; scrolling=yes",
                          src="shinyTexManual.pdf")
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "inst",
        fluidPage(
          sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 100, 50),
          tags$iframe(style="height:650px; width:100%; scrolling=yes",
                      src="shinyTexManual.pdf")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) { }
```

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1084.

Comment: Thanks Vishesh. It's fixed now after I moved the tags$iframe part to server after renderUI. I'm curious why it happens only in Chrome not in IE etc, and only when using multiple tabs in Shinydashboard.